# Variation in accuracy of data splitting before and after data augmentation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, regularization, data-augmentation

How much accuracy of the system varied/changes between two cases

1. Data augmentation before splitting
2. Data augmentation after splitting, only on training data

Is there any literature published?